# CSS - Overwrite image with background-image possible?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, overwrite

Is it possible to somehow overwrite an image with a new image with background-image?

I wan't to be able to change an image depending if it's retina or not with css.

Example

HTML:

```
<img id="foo" src="foo.png">
```

CSS:

```
#foo { background: url("bar.png") }
```

Comment: i'd use javascript for that purpose

Comment: This is good: https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

Comment: You can do it via CSS if the image has a container. Then you'll apply the background image to the container, and set the image inside the container to `display:none`, but I suspect there's a better solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems a bit of a convoluted strategy to me. Let me suggest a better option for dealing with retina-quality images. The simplest strategy I've seen for this (and I feel the best, at this stage) is to make the image twice the width and height you need it in Photoshop, then save it at a fairly low quality to keep file size down. In your HTML, or in your CSS, or both, set the desired width and height of the image. It will look great on both regular and retina screens that way, and still have a very small file size. And you only need one image, too, which is great.

Comment: Good suggestion... I've been trying to really squeeze down very-high res images for this purpose. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. It's a great tool in your arsenal as we deal with the growing pains of responsive images.

Comment: Yeah that might be the best way to go

Answer (score 1):

Try css3 `:before` :

```
img{
  display:none;
}
img:before{
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url("bar.png");
}
```